# Rails, Devise, OmniAuth: request additional fields and store them in the db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I'm a newbie in Rails.

So...in my Rails app, where I have OmniAuth Facebook integration, I want to add some fields, e.g., first name, last name and location, to my database.

I followed this [wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview), and I have a simple login, but without the extra fields (firstname, lastname, location).

So, I added this in my **config/initializers/devise.rb:**

```
require 'omniauth-facebook'
config.omniauth :facebook, '123456...', '123456...',
    scope: 'first_name, last_name, location',
    stategy_class: OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook
```

So, if I'm correct, the above will ask for these additional fields.

Now, in my model user.rb, I want to add 3 lines where it will pass the requested values to the database.

```
def self.find_for_facebook_omniauth(omniauth, signed_in_resource=nil)
  basic = {
      provider:  omniauth.provider,
      uid:       omniauth.uid,
      }
  User.where(basic).first || User.create(basic.merge(
      firstname: omniauth.info.firstname,  # these are the
      lastname:  omniauth.info.lastname,   # lines I'm not
      location:  omniauth.info.location,   # sure of
      email:     omniauth.info.email,
      password:  Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
      ))
end
```

Comment: It Looks ok. Did you try it ?

Comment: @Baldrick Yes and the controller redirects me to the `/users/sign_in` view

Comment: The `:scope` parameter in the `config_omniauth` statement is incorrect. Also `:strategy_class` is missing an 'r'. Can you try something like: `config.omniauth :facebook, "123456...", "123456...", :scope => "email, user_location, read_stream", :strategy_class => OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook`

Comment: @mccannf thanks for the help. The server needed a restart actually and the fields were `omniauth.info.first_name` also simple `:scope => 'location' ` works fine

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `omniauth` is `request.env["omniauth.auth"]`, then you may find additional fields are not include in the `.info` hash.

In this case it's safer to use `.extra.raw_info`, which will contain the fields for the additional scopes.

---

Here I requested the additional scope `user_hometown`, we can see it is missing in the `info` hash:

```
>> auth.info
=> #<OmniAuth::AuthHash::InfoHash email="dukedave@gmail.com" first_name="Dave" image="http://graph.facebook.com/508528599/picture?type=square" last_name="Tapley" name="Dave Tapley" nickname="dave.tapley" urls=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash Facebook="https://www.facebook.com/dave.tapley"> verified=true>
```

But present in `extra.raw_info` (after `gender`):

```
>> auth.extra.raw_info
=> #<OmniAuth::AuthHash email="dukedave@gmail.com" first_name="Dave" gender="male" hometown=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash id="105540216147364" name="Phoenix, Arizona"> id="508528599" last_name="Tapley" link="https://www.facebook.com/dave.tapley" locale="en_US" name="Dave Tapley" timezone=-7 updated_time="2013-11-22T22:10:26+0000" username="dave.tapley" verified=true>
```